# INVALID_REASON_UNSPECIFIED error with Google reCAPTCHA

Tags: recaptcha

We've been getting reports from users about the reCAPTCHA in our site failing when it shouldn't. In looking at our error log, we get about 10K errors a day with the INVALID_REASON_UNSPECIFIED error on the user token. Not a very helpful error message when trying to figure out what might be happening. Anyone have any experience with this error and what the possible causes could be? TIA.

Comment: No. And it is still happening. The only thing we can think of is that we're hitting it with too many requests per second. We're considering going back to making people pick stoplights again.

Comment: I get this error in my developer environment and I've just found out that the key I'm using was marked as a test key.